# Can't run pandas module even if it is installed

Tags: python, pandas, macos, error-handling

I've ran Pandas a lot of times on Raspbian, but I'm incurring in 'no module named..' error when I try to run on my OS X laptop. Maybe I have to deal with paths, but I don't have much confidence with route management.

This is what I see when I run pip3 show of the package. Seems to be in: /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages

[image: pip3 show pandas]

But this is what I see when I try to run a python3 script:
[image: import error]

Any suggestion?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can you run python3 --version and see output ?

Comment: Yes, it seems to be Python 3.6.3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the version check its clear that, you have `python3.7, python3.6` installations. So you verified `pip` is pointing to `3.7`, you have 2 options

1. Run it with correct version like `python3.7 pandas_try.py`
2. OR Change the alias of `python3` point to `python3.7` and use python3 as command. I think executing `alias python3=<path-to-python3.7>/python3.7` should do it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I think that this is the correct way to fix my problem, but the alias isn't correct I think, it returns me this error: https://ibb.co/6bqDcxH

Comment: Well the path to python3.7 depends on each machine. Find the path with 'which ' command and mark alias accordingly

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo python3 -m pip install wheel
```

I think you can try this.

pandas is distributed through pip , wheel

Comment: This is the result: https://ibb.co/RNcfHL4   it's linked to python2

Comment: pip3 uninstall pandas to Uninstall and reinstall pip install I can answer only so far. I have no idea any more sorry..

Comment: sudo python3 -m pip install wheel may help you

Comment: "Successfully installed wheel-0.34.2", but still doesn't work (thank you again for your time)